# MapView isn't showing android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm working with Google Maps API For Android.
I'm using a MapView since it's inside a Fragment in a ViewPager.
Unfortunately, it doesn't show as expected.
The compilator give me this error :

> [doInBackground] fail to retrieve url: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?myApp...

Why ? I'm using this in debug environment, it should look for the playstore.
Here is my manifest and my layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<permission
    android:name="faurecia.captordisplayer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="faurecia.captordisplayer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<!-- Permission pour utiliser la connexion internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Permission permettant de vérifier l'état de la connexion -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- Permission pour stocker des données en cache de la map -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".Application">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCKYeYG6IDbaRAs-rLmS3W_Zx8q742F5VU"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

my activity fragment :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@android:color/black">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="300px"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyCKYeYG6IDbaRAs-rLmS3W_Zx8q742F5VU"/>

    <faurecia.captordisplayer.view.GradientGauge
        android:id="@+id/gradientGauge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <faurecia.captordisplayer.view.EnginePowerGauge
        android:id="@+id/engineGauge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <faurecia.captordisplayer.view.Speedmeter
        android:id="@+id/speedmeter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <faurecia.captordisplayer.view.RankingGauge
        android:id="@+id/rankingGauge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my fragment code :

```
public class HMI0Fragment extends HMIFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
@Bind(R.id.mapview) MapView mMapView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    reScheduleTimerTask(TIMER_PERIOD);
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hmi0, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431), 2));

    // Polylines are useful for marking paths and routes on the map.
    map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
            .add(new LatLng(-33.866, 151.195))  // Sydney
            .add(new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431))  // Fiji
            .add(new LatLng(21.291, -157.821))  // Hawaii
            .add(new LatLng(37.423, -122.091))  // Mountain View
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the explanation but the trouble was elsewhere.
When including a MapView inside a Fragment, you have to override all the fragment state (OnResume, OnPause etc) and use the MapView. 
Here is a sample :

```
public class HMI0Fragment extends HMIFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private static int TIMER_PERIOD = 4000;
private static String NAME = "HMI0";

@Bind(R.id.mapview) MapView mMapView;

private boolean mapsSupported = true;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());

    if (mMapView != null) {
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    initializeMap();
}

private void initializeMap() {
    if ( mapsSupported) {
        mMapView = (MapView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        //setup markers etc...
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    reScheduleTimerTask(TIMER_PERIOD);
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hmi0, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431), 2));

    // Polylines are useful for marking paths and routes on the map.
    map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
            .add(new LatLng(-33.866, 151.195))  // Sydney
            .add(new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431))  // Fiji
            .add(new LatLng(21.291, -157.821))  // Hawaii
            .add(new LatLng(37.423, -122.091))  // Mountain View
    );
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
    initializeMap();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To use the [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/android/), you must register your app project on the Google Developers Console and get a Google API key which you can add to your app. The type of API key you need is an Android key.

Follow instructions here to set up a maps API key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert

- Make a project in the Google Developers Console
- Generate a key to use the Maps API
- Add the key to your android manifest

Just call the `onCreate()` method before you call `getMapAsync()` and once the callback is called, you need to call `onResume()` on the MapView object.

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

if (getView() != null) {

final MapView mapView = (MapView)getView().findViewById(R.id.mapView);

mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(match.match.LocationLatitude, match.match.LocationLongitude);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordinates).title(match.match.LocationAddress));
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 15));
mapView.onResume();
}
}
}
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return false;
}
}
```

Here's a demo app demonstrate how to use Maps API for Android using SupportMapFragment - getMapAsync: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos